# Resize jpeg stream on memory with .NET, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm working with WPF, .NET 3.5, C#. I have jpeg file byte array in memory loaded from database, and I'd like to resize it to smaller size on memory.

- input is jpeg file byte array in memory.
- output is jpeg file byte array in memory, presenting resized jpeg image.
- resize (and re-encode) should be done on memory, without using FILE.
- resize can be done with bi-liner operation.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: [Thumbnail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx) ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If it was me I would explore the Image class but I don't do WPF so don't know if there is a better way. The Image class has worked for me when I needed to work with common image formats. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MikeCheel, I googled for "Image resize C#" kind words and tried few hours to find a solution but failed. I could not solve my issue with Image class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search yields an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0fsyd4e(v=vs.110).aspx) stating how to do this.

A simple example:

```
System.Drawing.Image source = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Z:\Temp\temp.bmp");
System.Drawing.Image destination = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(128, 128);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(destination))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
    g.DrawImage(source, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0,0,128,128), new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0,source.Width, source.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

destination.Save(@"Z:\Temp\outpt.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Note my example uses files, but that is just for the loading and saving.  All of the work is done in memory and you can load and save from memory streams if that suits your workflow better.

Comment: This method permit you to choose the interpolation algorithm , which is an advantage. But as you use WPF, it is better to use BitmapSource wheras Bitmap.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, your code worked. I needed to modify code not to use file as you mentioned but I could get what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this function :

```
public static BitmapImage BitmapImageFromBitmapSourceResized(BitmapSource bitmapSource, int newWidth)
    {
    BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
    encoder.Save(memoryStream);

    bImg.BeginInit();
    bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
    bImg.DecodePixelWidth = newWidth;
    bImg.EndInit();
    memoryStream.Close();
    return bImg;
}
```

The use of this function is recommanded by microsoft, because the image is not saved in its original size but with the size *newWidth*. It can avoid you memory overflow if the user enter huge images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code but resut is not what I wanted. Since this does not perform re-encoding, memory stream of returned BitmapImage is not changed. I need re-encoded, smaller memory stream for resized image.